# Networkx KeyError: 'source' with from_pandas_edgelist for undirected edgelist

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have an edgelist in a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
    topic   neighbor
0   K       Kl
1   K       Pr
2   Kl      TS
3   Pr      Kl
4   Pr      Pr
```

When I turn this into a Graph (using networkx as nx) with `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df)` it gives me KeyError: 'source'.

It works when I specify a source and target `G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, "topic", "neighbor")` but this is an undirected Graph so I do not really want a source and target.

Is this the way it has to be done? Will specifying a source and target have implications for later calculations of degree_centrality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, creating an undirected network from a dataframe requires specifying source and target.

It's not necessary, but to be sure that the graph is undirected, one can specify [`create_using` kwarg](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html):

```py
from networkx import Graph, from_pandas_edgelist

df = ...

# note that Graph is the default setting, so specifying
# create_using=Graph is optional
G = from_pandas_edgelist(df, "topic", "neighbor", create_using=Graph)


print(G.is_directed())
# False
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.read_clipboard()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  topic neighbor
0     K       Kl
1     K       Pr
2    Kl       TS
3    Pr       Kl
4    Pr       Pr
```

Use `source` and `target` parameters:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='topic', target='neighbor')
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

Output:

[image]